# Pessimistic locking and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, locking

I've encountered this comment on reddit:

> I love Postgres but the one thing I wish is had is pessimistic
>   locking. It's just such a huge help when you need multi-statement
>   queries when multiple sources of writes against the same data are
>   coming in.

https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2yl65b/goodbye_mongodb_hello_postgresql/

But then there's this:

> Row-level Lock Modes
>
> FOR UPDATE causes the rows retrieved by the SELECT
>   statement to be locked as though for update. This prevents them from
>   being locked, modified or deleted by other transactions until the
>   current transaction ends.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html

Is that or is it not the same thing as pessimistic locking?

Comment: Yes, it is. Anything else?

Comment: The comment on reddit does not make sense to. Seems like that guy did not understand how updates work in a relational database. I _think_ what he/she maybe meant was concurrent _reads_ to be blocked as well when any write operation is going on

Comment: 1) Basically Postgres is a joke.  The notion of MVCC is false, there is no Concurrency Control, it is MV-non-CC.  It only works when their "2PL" Lock Manager is added on top of MV-non-CC, Postgres does all its internal concurrency resolution using its Lock Manager. 2) Pessimistic Locking is a specific bad "method," not just increased locks.  3) Since it does not work, eg,. as per your question, it allows the developer to set explicit locks.  Which is dangerous: anything less that perfect causes more lock contention.

Comment: 4) The SQL method, the answer to your question, is to SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION REPEATABLE READ.  But PostGres is not SQL compliant.